# How to fix duplicate data location when use both redux and class object

Tags: design-patterns, redux

I am trying to refactor my `redux`'s reducer function, my intention is to move data manipulating function into a separated class. This should be like:

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  notes: []
}

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_NOTES':
      let newState = Note.addNew(action.note);
      return newState;
    ...
  }
}
```

note.js

```
class Note {
  notes = [];

  function addNew(note) {
    return [...this.notes, note];
  }
}
```

My problem here is `notes` is stored in multiple location: the `state` parameter of reducer function and `notes` inside Note class. One way to fix this is to remove `notes` from the class and modify addNew function to `addNew(notes, newNote)` but this way I have to pass the data to every manipulating functions.

Are there any better solutions for it?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much on point here but there is just one problem. Let me give you brief intro on how redux works.

In redux language your addNew function is called Action. You don't need to pass state i.e. all your notes to reducer. reducer will automatically gets it. Below is the way you dispatch action.

This is how redux works.

1. You dispatch action(update event) to the state from the component you are working in.

See line 9 [here](https://github.com/logeekal/ReduxExperiments/blob/master/skypey/src/containers/MessageInput.js)
You can pass anything you want to that particular action. Let's assume you pass note to action addNew. Code will be

```
    const sendNote = note => {
        store.dispatch(addNew(note);
    };
```

2. Now once you have dispatched action. You action will catch that particular action and forward it to reducers. 
   Now action should always be of the form

   {
   type : 'ADD_NOTE',
   payload : note
   }
   Take notice of type and payload. Now this is an action to add Note. Now this action will be sent to all of the reducer. For reference check [here](https://github.com/logeekal/ReduxExperiments/blob/master/skypey/src/actions/index.js) line 15.
3. Finally reducer catches your action and gets the state automatically. Remember, you only need to pass initialState as the default value. It always gets the complete state.

Now your reducer will change as below:

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_NOTES':
      return state.notes.push(action.payload);
  }
}
```

This will update your state for which the shape is :

**State**
{notes : [] }

I would strongly recommend you go through [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-redux-the-worlds-easiest-guide-to-beginning-redux-c695f45546f6) long and in-depth article where Ohans helps you developing a real world application using Redux.